# websocket node.js module "ws" not working - infinite load

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I've been through to ws documentation and have copied and pasted their external http/s server example character for character. When I run the server I don't get any errors but when I go to my browser and navigate to the local host on the specified port number, the page is stuck in this infinite load state. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have for my server app (copied from ws example):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = https.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('backendSSL/backend.crt', 'utf8'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('backendSSL/backend.key', 'utf8')
});
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log("new client connected");
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

This is what I have in my html file:

```js
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

Comment: you need to connect from client side through a websocket connection and not open it in browser
Read further there would be some code for client side script.

Comment: I have a index.html in the same directory with: 

const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080"); 

      socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        console.log("we are connected");
      })

But still does infinite load. Also how does it know to run index.html?

Comment: so basically you should open ```index.html``` and it should work . is that what you are doing?  dont open localhost:8080

Comment: No I'm navigating to https://localhost:8080/

Comment: thats the problem...you must start index.html which is client . not localhost:8080 because its websicket connection and its meant to run as a Daemon so you must not open it directly.

Comment: if i open index.html that's  just running from my computer. It doesnt do anything over server

Comment: it should even though its running locally. are you able to get console log ? try inspecting under networks tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232722/discussion-between-prashanthth-kumar-and-normajean).